# in dropdown the selected option must be highlighted

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, dropdown

i have a dropdown in my code. i have tried all the solution online to highlight the selected option
but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working.

````
                  <asp:linkbutton ID="ReportsLink" type="button" OnClientClick="return false;"  class="dropbtn"  runat ="server"  CausesValidation="false" cssclass="MenuItem">
            <img alt="WorkFlow"   class="MenuIcon" src="Assets/img/Reports.png" />
            <asp:label  ID="Label1" style="color:white;" runat="server" Text="Reports" />
          </asp:linkbutton>

         <ul class="dropdown-content" id="myDIV">

   <li><a href="xyz.aspx"class="color active">xyz</a></li>
  <%-- <li><a href="abc.aspx"class="color">abc</a></li> --%>
    <li><a href="pqr.aspx"class="color">pqr</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div> ```

this is the css!!

```.active{
    background-color: #2864DC;
                           color:white;
}```


 ``` var url = window.location;
        $('.dropdown-content a').filter(function() {
            return this.href == url;
    }).parent().addClass('active'); ```

i just want the li to be highlighted!
````

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working Example.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `window.location` it returns a `Location` object.

In order to compare you should use `var url = window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

You can Replace this CSS

```
a.color.active {
    background-color: #2864DC;
    color:white;
}
```

OR

```
a.active {
    background-color: #2864DC;
    color:white;
}
```

I Think it's very helpful.

Comment: actually if i do this the first option does get highlighted, but it doesn't change when i choose some other option